# Extracting specific Information from a website using BeautifulSoup (Python)

Tags: python

I am accessing the following website to extract a list of stocks:

http://www.barchart.com/stocks/performance/12month.php

I am using the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url=raw_input("http://www.barchart.com/stocks/performance/12month.php")
r = requests.get("http://www.barchart.com/stocks/performance/12month.php")
data = r.text
soup =BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

The problem is I am getting a lot of other information that is not needed. I wanted to ask what would be a method that would just give me the stock names and nothing else.

Comment: Are you asking a) If there is one already? b) If we should write one for you? - Case a) Most likely. Case b) No. Please narrow the question down.

Comment: I am asking if there is a way already. Since I dont know how to do it directly, I am copying the file into a text file and extracting keywords from there. I dont know if that is the fastest way of doing this though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
r = requests.get("http://www.barchart.com/stocks/performance/12month.php")
html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tds = soup.find_all("td", {"class": "ds_name"})
for td in tds:
    print td.a.text
```

If you look at the source code of the page, you will find that all you need is in a table. To be specific, the stocks' names are in `<td></td>` whose `class="ds_name"`. So, that's it.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Did not know about soup.find_all